# NET8 MAUI using GoToAsync doesn't erase the viewmodel

Tags: c#, maui

In my MAUI application with NET8, to navigate from one page to another I use something like

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(WordEdit)}?WordID={id}", true);
```

So the page *WordEdit* shows a form when the user can type some details and then save. When the user saves, I send the application back to the calling page with

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
```

If I call the page again, the ViewModel has the old data. I thought that using `GoTo` disposes the page and if I want to open the same page, the application is recreating a new instance.

How can I implement the correct navigation?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: `GoToAsync()` doesn't dispose existing Pages or ViewModels, that would make adding pages on top of other pages or switching between tabs impossible. How did you register the ViewModel and the Page? Are you using Shell's Dependency Injection?

Comment: Have you tried absolute routes, e.g. `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WordEdit)}?WordID={id}", true);`. For more information see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation`

Comment: @StephenQuan yes, I'm using dependency injection for the viewodels.

Comment: @StephenQuan is the absolute route dispose the page?

Comment: `If I call the page again, the ViewModel has the old data` I just saw you passed a  parameter `WordID` to page `WordEdit`. What's the `ViewModel` ? What data is still there?

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation is correct. This is the way shell works.

You can always give up on shell, and construct your own pages, push and pop them from the navigation stack, and have full control.

Let is think for a second on your main problem: some interface field is filled with old data.

Should your first idea how to solve this, be to force Shell to reconstruct pages and view models?

New page, new view model, new service1, new service2, new service3... initialization of data, and also, destruction of old page, destruction of old view model, free all resources, etc.

Compare all this non-sense above, to `Name = ""`.

It is more than clear what is the correct way to handle the situation.